# how to create an Eclipse View inside eclipse bundle class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to create an eclipse View using eclipse bundle project.
This link shows the creation of Bundle Project-
https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_126_creating_an_osgi

Now my query is how to add an view and other SWT content , like adding plugin.xml into eclipse Bundle project

Comment: This is far to broad for a SO question. You need to read up on Eclipse plugin development in the Eclipse help and then add more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use WindowBuilder http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/ included in Plugin Development Tools.

Do File / New / Other... then seklct WindowBuilder / SWT Designer / RCP / ViewPart for e3 or Eclipse 4 / ViewPart for e4. It will create necessary files for you.